# How Sequence Matters in Laravel query builder for mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, sequence, query-builder

**The complied query has different sequence from the code.**
The query works but I don't know why it works!

Here is the business:

I get the `roomId` by the `$userId`, and then I get all the `playerId` by the `roomId`

Steps:

1. in Table `room_player_relations`, I get a row where `playerId` = `$userId`.
2. in Table `room_player_relations`, I get all the rows where `roomId` = the `roomId` of the row found in point 1.
3. select `playerId` from the rows found in point 2.

Here is the code:

```
$players = DB::table('room_player_relations as t1')
        ->where('t1.playerId',$userId)
        ->join('room_player_relations as t2','t1.roomId','=','t2.roomId')            
        ->select('t2.playerId')
        ->get();
```

Here is the query seen in the debugbar:

```
select `t2`.`playerId` from `room_player_relations` as `t1` 
inner join `room_player_relations` as `t2` 
on `t1`.`roomId` = `t2`.`roomId` 
where `t1`.`playerId` = '1'
```

**It looks stupid because it join 2 the same tables together,** the `where` is put afterward. But it works. Please tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: Order of events on an eloquent query doesn't really matter; there's stuff happening behind the scenes to translate your `->where()`, `->join()`, etc. into the correct syntax (`SELECT * FROM ...  JOIN ... WHERE ...`) for the current DB, including placement/ordering, etc.

Comment: In an SQL query the `WHERE` clause *always* comes after the `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: So how does DB does behind, which make the query logical? Joining Table 1 to Table 1 still looks meaningless.

Comment: I can't speak to your query, but self-joins happen all the time; really just depends on what you're trying to accomplish. As a quick example, recursive relationships, using `parent` and `child(ren)` logic, requires joining the same table to itself: `SELECT * FROM table AS parent JOIN table AS child ON table.parent_id = parent.id ...`

Answer (score 0):

I find out `INNER JOIN`-ing two table is not sticking two tables together, but matching all the possible ways of the matching key (`roomId`in my example). I can actually see the result of `INNER JOIN` by the following query:

```
select * from `room_player_relations` as `t1` 
inner join `room_player_relations` as `t2` 
on `t1`.`roomId` = `t2`.`roomId`
```

> playerId roomId playerId roomId
>
> 2       2       2       2
>
> 3       2       2       2
>
> 1       2       2       2
>
> 2       2       3       2
>
> 3       2       3       2
>
> 1       2       3       2
>
> 4       1       4       1
>
> 5       1       4       1
>
> 4       1       5       1
>
> 5       1       5       1
>
> 2       2       1       2
>
> 3       2       1       2
>
> 1       2       1       2